# Rails Scope is returning an array instead of an ActiveRecord_Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

An `Agency` has_many `Contacts`.  In a search form: A user enters a name of a contact.  Once submitted, the app returns all Agencies that have an associated Contact with that entered name.

Two Models:

```
#models/agency.rb
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts, dependent: :destroy

    scope :by_contact_name, ->(contact_name)
                              {joins(:contacts)
                               .select("CONCAT('first_name', ' ', 'last_name')AS 'full_name')")
                               .where("full_name LIKE ?", contact_name) 
                              }
end

#models/contact.rb
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agency
end
```

So basically: A `contact` has the attributes: `first_name`, and `last_name`.  In the search form, The prompt to the user is: **Enter the Contact's Full Name**.  Then in the Controller, I call that Agency scope of `by_contact_name`, pass in the value that the user entered, join the tables, create that column of `full_name` because it doesn't exist in the database, and then query by it with `LIKE`.

I hope that makes sense!  The scope works, but the issue is that it returns an array when I want it to return an ActiveRecord_Relation.

I think the issue is that I have `select` within the scope, but I don't know any other way to do it.

**My overall question is this:**

If I call `Agency.all.by_contact_name("Joe").class`, how can I make it so that it returns `Agency::ActiveRecord_Relation` instead of: `Array`?

Comment: What version of Rails?

Comment: @zetetic Rails 4.1.1

Comment: I ask because old versions of Rails would sometimes appear to return an Array when actually they were returning a relation, but that does not appear to be the issue here. Adding `select` to the clause should not affect what is returned.

Comment: @zetetic do you know how to do this and return an active relation?

Comment: It should not return an array. In what context did you notice it was in array ? In the console for example it will trigger inspect and return an array, but it's actually an active_relation....

Comment: @charlysisto for me in 4.2.1 it returns a relation, not an array. Might depend on the Rails version, but AFAIK that behavior went away quite some time ago. There may some other factor due to the Rails configuration/gems that causes the effect Neil is seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
#models/agency.rb
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts, dependent: :destroy
  scope :by_contact_name, -> (name){joins(:contacts).merge(Contact.by_name(name))}
end

#models/contact.rb
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agency
  scope :by_name, -> (full_name){where("CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) LIKE ?", "%#{full_name}%")}
end
```

**Usage**:

```
@agencies = Agency.by_contact_name("joe s")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would build the full name in Rails, but concatenate in the where clause to be able to query on it.

```
{joins(:contacts)
.where("CONCAT('first_name', ' ', 'last_name') LIKE ?", contact_name)}
```